# Reading text from other sites written by angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want to read the value 10059 from another site. It contained in the p tag looks like this, and i want it.

```
<p class="currency_desc">10059 usd</p>
```

What I did in rails app:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri :: HTML (open ('http://sample.com'))
content = doc.to_html
....
....
```

But the content I got about is:

```
<p class="currency_desc">{{ buy_rates}} usd</p>
```

It is written in angularjs.
How do I do it?

Comment: You need to download everything, html and javascript. Then _run_ the javascript and inspect the page. In short, do what browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nokogiri`'s [commands](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri#synopsis) to search for element in your response then get the value you want, something like:

```
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  buy_rates = page.search("p.currency_desc").text()
```

Some searches `page.search("p.currency_desc")` can return an Array of elements which you can iterate through if the page has more then one element with same class and tag

Comment: That's works with static `html` and doesnt with dynamic.

Comment: Зелёный: I also think so, is there no way to read `dynamic html `?

Comment: One option is you can use a combination of `nokogiri` and `phantomJs` or maybe `phantomJs` and `watir` gems to parse and read dynamic html